# Visual Studio for mac: how to run a terminal

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I'm new to Visual Studio on mac, can someone show where we can run a terminal window to execute some git commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Terminal window is not a part of the built-in tools within Visual Studio for Mac. There might be some add-ins or extension for this, but I am not aware.

However, there is a GUI Git tool called 'Version Control' which is integrated to VS, you can use it.

If you still want to use a terminal window, you can open a separate terminal window, outside of the VS. Alternatively there is an VS fro Mac [add-in](https://github.com/yuv4ik/vsmacdeepclean) that allows you to open a terminal window (again outside of the VS) on any solution's dir.

**UPDATE:**
You can open any directory from Visual Studio for Mac in a terminal by right-clicking any project directory > Tools > Open in Terminal

Answer (score 5):

In Mac VS2019, I found access to Terminal
under Solution navigation
Select your Project
Crl-Click (hold)
Navigate to Tool
Open in Terminal

It seems to work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studion for Mac Previews now include a terminal as of April 2020

Tools->Show Terminal Window or <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/meet-visual-studio-for-macs-new-integrated-terminal/#:~:text=%20Meet%20Visual%20Studio%20for%20Mac%E2%80%99s%20New%20Integrated,at%20any%20time.%20%20...%20%20More%20](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/meet-visual-studio-for-macs-new-integrated-terminal/#:%7E:text=%20Meet%20Visual%20Studio%20for%20Mac%E2%80%99s%20New%20Integrated,at%20any%20time.%20%20...%20%20More%20)